# when $\kappa > 2^{\omega}$,$ 2^{\kappa}$ is not separable w.r.t the discrete topology

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

When I want to prove the title, the following hint is provided. say: If $D\subset2^{\kappa}$, is countable, there are $\alpha<\beta$ s.t. for all $f\in D$, $f(\alpha)=f(\beta)$.

My question is how to prove this hint. I guess a combinatorical argument will be used.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Let $D=\{f_n:n\in\omega\}$, and for each $\alpha<\kappa$ define a function

$$\varphi_\alpha:\omega\to 2:n\mapsto f_n(\alpha)\;.$$

How many distinct functions from $\omega$ to $2$ are there? And how many $\alpha<\kappa$ are there?

Comment: Thank you! I see the point.

Comment: @Targaryen: You’re welcome!